# Limiting recursion depth when searching for folders

Tags: powershell, recursion, powershell-4.0

I am trying to limit the recursion depth for a folder search script that I wrote. I am trying to limit to **up to five levels deep**

Essentially I want to get something like this:

```
h:\demo\1st level
h:\demo\1st level\2nd level
h:\demo\1st level\2nd level\3rd level
h:\demo\1st level\2nd level\3rd level\4th level\
h:\demo\1st level\2nd level\3rd level\4th level\5th level
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
function Get-ChildItemRecursive {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]

        [string]$FullName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]

        [int]$Depth = 0
    )

    Process {
        if ($Depth -ne 1) {
            $newDepth = if ($Depth -gt 1) { $Depth - 1 } else { $Depth }
            Get-ChildItem -Path $FullName -Directory |
                Get-ChildItemRecursive -Depth $newDepth
        }
        else {
            Get-ChildItem -Path $FullName -Directory
        }
        Get-ChildItem -Path $FullName -File
    }
}

Get-ChildItemRecursive -FullName 'H:\demo\' |
   Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | select @{Name='Date Modified';
Expression = {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}},
             @{Name='Owner';E=
                 {(($_.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split('\'))[1])}},
             FullName | Export-Csv 'H:\demo\scan1.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

The output I am getting:

```
Get-ChildItemRecursive -FullName 'H:\demo\' |
    Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | select   @{Name='Date Modified';
Expression = {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}},
             @{Name='Owner';E=
                 {(($_.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split('\'))[1])}},
             FullName | Export-Csv 'H:\demo\scan1.csv' -NoTypeInformation

PS H:\> Get-ChildItemRecursive
cmdlet Get-ChildItemRecursive at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
FullName: H:\demo\

Directory: H:\demo

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name

----                -------------     ------ ----

-a---         6/21/2017   4:12 PM     248472 lastrun.csv

-a---         6/26/2017  11:27 AM        706 demo1.csv

-a---         6/21/2017   1:38 PM       7861 4thrun06-21-17.csv

-a---         6/21/2017  11:50 AM       2182 firstrun06-21-17.csv

-a---         6/21/2017   2:41 PM       1334 demo.csv

-a---         6/21/2017  12:24 PM      20985 3rdrun06-21-17.csv

-a---         6/26/2017   2:24 PM          0 scan1.csv

-a---         6/21/2017   4:22 PM       3671 sort-parent-subfolder.csv

-a---         6/21/2017  12:25 PM       7298 2ndrun06-21-17.csv

-a---         6/22/2017   4:46 PM       4637 2ndfolderRun6-22-17.csv

-a---         6/22/2017  10:59 AM      28540 firstfolder.csv

-a---         6/22/2017   4:59 PM     104618 4thfolder.csv


PS H:\>
```

Comment: Why not just upgrade and use the `-depth` parameter? Otherwise, change your single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: @Nick that is only available in powershell 5 and my company wants to remain at 4. I tried changing to double quotes Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "H:\demo\*\*\*\*\*" but it does not seem to limit everything to level 5 folders

Comment: @Nick I removed the wildcards and recurse, but its still not displaying appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

You can't limit recursion depth for `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` in PowerShell v4 or earlier. The respective parameter was [added with PowerShell v5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem):

> **-Depth**
>
> This parameter, added in Powershell 5.0 enables you to control the depth of recursion. You use both the -Recurse and the -Depth parameter to limit the recursion.
>
> Type: UInt32
>   Parameter Sets: (All)
>   Aliases:
>
> Required: False
>   Position: Named
>   Default value: None
>   Accept pipeline input: False
>   Accept wildcard characters: False

And your attempt doesn't work, because `-Path 'H:\demo\*\*\*\*\*'` gets the folder contents from **exactly** 5 levels deep. It doesn't include content from above that level.

If you can't upgrade to PowerShell v5 you can implement a recursive function that calls `Get-ChildItem` without `-Recurse`. Something like this:

```
function Get-ChildItemRecursive {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string]$FullName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [int]$Depth = 0
  )

  Process {
    if ($Depth -ne 1) {
      $newDepth = if ($Depth -gt 1) { $Depth - 1 } else { $Depth }
      Get-ChildItem -Path $FullName -Directory | Get-ChildItemRecursive -Depth $newDepth
    }
    Get-ChildItem -Path $FullName
  }
}

Get-ChildItemRecursive -FullName 'H:\demo' -Depth 5 |
    Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} |
    ...
```

Comment: this results in an infinite loop and does not search the exact path specified. can you show me how this code would work with my path and parameters? thank you.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I am still confused as to how my folder path will work with this code. is there anyway you can add an example path? (e.g. H:\demo\..)  Also, how will I be able to add these parameters:     select @{Name='Date Modified'; Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}},
        @{Name='Owner';E={(($_.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split('\'))[1])}},
        FullName |
    Export-Csv 'H:\Main Scans\Folder scan\de.csv' -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Replacing `Get-ChildItem` with `Get-ChildItemRecursive` in your code should suffice. But I just noticed that the code was missing a `Process {...}` block. See updated answer.

Comment: I am getting a prompt stating "supply values for the following parameters: Fullname:" is there any way to bypass this? Also, If I  input "h:/demo/" it doesn't properly display all the parameters.

Comment: Here is the code that I have:                                                                    
       `Get-ChildItemRecursive -FullName 'H:\demo' | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} |  select @{Name='Date Modified'; Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}},@{Name='Owner';E={(($_.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split('\'))[1])}}, FullName |  Export-Csv 'H:\demo\scan1.csv' -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: The code works fine for me. Please double-check that you didn't miss anything.

Comment: I am correct to call the function without any variable attached?

Comment: What variable? The function has a mandatory parameter `-FullName` and an optional parameter `-Depth`. When the latter is omitted recursion depth is unlimited. Please update your question with the code you currently have and describe what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: This seemed to have worked! sorry about the confusion. Just one more note; the program seems to get the depth that is exactly specified in the  [int]$Depth = 0 and does not go through depths 1 -5

Comment: You if you want limited recursion you need to call `Get-ChildItemRecursive` **with** the parameter `-Depth` initially. I thought that was rather obvious.

Comment: is there anyway I can set it to go through depths 1 through 5; If I add the -depth 5 it will only display folders from that depth.

Comment: If you want the folders into which the function recurses along with the files adjust the function as show in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! sorry for being such an annoyance.. any resources that you would recommend I utilize in order to get a better understanding of powershell? Thank you again!

Answer (score -3):

It's no so beautiful, but you can try this:

```
# First lvl
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'D:\Test' | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | select  @{Name='Date Modified'; Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}},  @{Name='Owner';E={(($_.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split('\'))[1])}}, @{Name='FullnameLvl0';E={(($_.Fullname.Split('\')[0] + "\" + $_.Fullname.Split('\')[1]))}} | add-content D:\Test\test.csv

# Sec lvl
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path 'D:\Test' | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | select  @{Name='Date Modified'; Expression={$_.LastWriteTime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}},  @{Name='Owner';E={(($_.GetAccessControl().Owner.Split('\'))[1])}}, @{Name='FullnameLvl1';E={(($_.Fullname.Split('\')[0] + "\" + $_.Fullname.Split('\')[1])+ "\" + $_.Fullname.Split('\')[2])}} | add-content D:\Test\test.csv

#...etc
```